# TextView in RelativeLayout improper alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, android-relativelayout

I need to implement the following UI:
[image]

For this, I am using the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_image0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/news_cell0_imageview_min_height"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/news0_cell_image_overlay_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/news_image0"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/news_image0"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/news_image0"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/news_image0"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/news_image0"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/news_image0"
        android:background="@drawable/news_cell0_overlay_gradient">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_title0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/colorNewsCellType0TitleText"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_cell0_textview_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/news_cell0_title_text_size"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Into the ImageView I am loading image using Picasso from a URL. I am getting output correctly in most of the devices, but in some of the devices running android less than Lollipop, this shows up like the screenshot below. The text shows up at the top, instead of bottom. But I have set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the TextView. The `RelativeLayout` is rendered correctly, and it fits the image(it has a background gradient, which can clearly be seen at the bottom of the image).

[image]

What is causing this problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" for news0_cell_image_overlay_layout

Answer (score 2):

You can try with **[FRAMELAYOUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)**

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
>   overlapping each other.

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView 
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

   <TextView
      android:text="Hi.."
      android:textSize="17sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center|bottom"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I need the RelativeLayout to add a background.

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/news_cell0_overlay_gradient"` This portion is important

Comment: @HarikrishnanT well, See http://www.android-examples.com/overlap-view-by-putting-another-view-above-in-relativelayout-android/

Comment: @HarikrishnanT could you share values of `news_cell0_imageview_min_height`

Comment: I have overlapped with the Relative layout, and the RelativeLayout is correctly rendered, it is the TextView inside the RelativeLayout that is misbehaving.

Comment: `news_cell0_imageview_min_height` is 150dp

Comment: This is working perfect in all devices above Lollipop, but below Lollipop the issue is happening.

Comment: for test case ,add `android:gravity="center_vertical|left|bottom"` .Remove `start`in textview section .

Comment: This doesn't work. The comment Raj posted under the question actually worked, even though I have no idea how this issue came or how that fixed it.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT okay .Sloppy mistake .Move ahead

Answer (score 1):

You can try this layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_image0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_title0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/news_image0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="fsdsdfdsdsfsdfsdf"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:typeface="monospace"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need the RelativeLayout to add a background.

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/news_cell0_overlay_gradient"`
This portion is important